# Mailchimp API v3 if statement

Tags: php, mailchimp

I have a simplified Mailchimp API call to our specific list to see if a user is subscribed or not.  Everything works fine however we want to take that information and perform other functions based on the result.  For example if they are not subscribed we would like to add them to that list.  If they are we would like to display a message.  The trouble I'm running into is my if statement is not working.  Please see below.  By all accounts the page should say "have a good day".  But nothing is returning.

```
$api = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-us6';
$server = 'us6';
$listid = 'xxxxxx';
$debug = 1;
$email = 'EMAIL THAT IS ON THE LIST';

function mc_checklist($email, $debug, $apikey, $listid, $server) {
    $userid = md5($email);
    $auth = base64_encode( 'user:'. $apikey );
    $data = array(
        'apikey'        => $apikey,
        'email_address' => $email
    );
    $json_data = json_encode($data);
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://'.$server.'.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/'.$listid.'/members/' . $userid);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json',
        'Authorization: Basic '. $auth));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP-MCAPI/2.0');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($debug) {
        var_dump($result);
    }
    $json = json_decode($result);
    echo $json->{'status'};

    die();
}

mc_checklist($email, $debug, $api, $listid, $server );

if ($json->{'status'} == "subscribed") {
echo "Have a good day!";
}
```

RESULTS

```
    string(2669) "{"id":"b975283169c19f4072fc79202b4c5ede","email_address":"sgembar1@gmail.com","unique_email_id":"7a5737201e","email_type":"html","status":"subscribed","merge_fields":{"FNAME":"Stephen","LNAME":"Gembar","MMERGE3":"33510","MMERGE4":"08/08"},"stats":{"avg_open_rate":0,"avg_click_rate":0},"ip_signup":"","timestamp_signup":"","ip_opt":"107.170.5.35","timestamp_opt":"2016-12-13T21:42:06+00:00","member_rating":2,"last_changed":"2016-12-13T21:42:06+00:00","language":"","vip":false,"email_client":"","location":{"latitude":0,"longitude":0,"gmtoff":0,"dstoff":0,"country_code":"","timezone":""},"list_id":"df8eaa3df5","_links":[{"rel":"self","href":"https://us6.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/df8eaa3df5/members/b975283169c19f4072fc79202b4c5ede","method":"GET","targetSchema":"https://us6.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Definitions/Lists/Members/Response.json"},{"rel":"parent","href":"https://us6.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/df8eaa3df5/members","method":"GET","targetSchema":"https://us6.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Definitions/Lists/Members/CollectionResponse.json","schema":"https://us6.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/CollectionLinks/Lists/Members.json"},{"rel":"update","href":"https://us6.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/df8eaa3df5/members/b975283169c19f4072fc79202b4c5ede","method":"PATCH","targetSchema":"https://us6.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Definitions/Lists/Members/Response.json","schema":"https://us6.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Definitions/Lists/Members/PATCH.json"},{"rel":"upsert","href":"https://us6.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/df8eaa3df5/members/b975283169c19f4072fc79202b4c5ede","method":"PUT","targetSchema":"https://us6.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Definitions/Lists/Members/Response.json","schema":"https://us6.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Definitions/Lists/Members/PUT.json"},{"rel":"delete","href":"https://us6.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/df8eaa3df5/members/b975283169c19f4072fc79202b4c5ede","method":"DELETE"},{"rel":"activity","href":"https://us6.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/df8eaa3df5/members/b975283169c19f4072fc79202b4c5ede/activity","method":"GET","targetSchema":"https://us6.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Definitions/Lists/Members/Activity/Response.json"},{"rel":"goals","href":"https://us6.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/df8eaa3df5/members/b975283169c19f4072fc79202b4c5ede/goals","method":"GET","targetSchema":"https://us6.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Definitions/Lists/Members/Goals/Response.json"},{"rel":"notes","href":"https://us6.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/df8eaa3df5/members/b975283169c19f4072fc79202b4c5ede/notes","method":"GET","targetSchema":"https://us6.api.mailchimp.com/schema/3.0/Definitions/Lists/Members/Notes/CollectionResponse.json"}]}" subscribed
```

Comment: can you provide more info?  what is in the $result variable?  Have you tried echo'ing $result?

Comment: Echoing $result returns nothing.  I will modify my post to show the results

Comment: You typed "my if statement is not working"... is that this one? `if ($json->{'status'} == "subscribed") {` was that before the `die` statement was added?

Comment: No but thank you I figured out the problem was the if statement needed to be inside the curl and before die()